# UIImage is equal to

Tags: swift, uiimage

I need to check if a file loaded into an `UIImage` object file is equal to another image and execute some actions if so. Unfortunately, it's not working.

```
emptyImage = UIImage(named: imageName)

if(image1.image != emptyImage) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something
}
```

The above code always enters the `if` branch.

Comment: It should enter the if statement. It should not enter the else statement.

Comment: See my answer below. You should use `.isEqual` and not `!=`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can convert your `UIImage` instances to `NSData` instances and compare them.

```
if let emptyImage = UIImage(named: "empty") {
    let emptyData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(emptyImage)
    let compareImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1.image)

    if let empty = emptyData, compareTo = compareImageData {
        if empty.isEqualToData(compareTo) {
            // Empty image is the same as image1.image
        } else {
            // Empty image is not equal to image1.image
        }
    } else {
        // Creating NSData from Images failed
    }
}
```

Comment: In case someone is looking at this for Swift 3: `isEqualToData` does not exist anymore, instead, you can just use the `==` operator between 2 `Data` objects directly, just like any other 2 variables of the same type.

Answer (score 20):

You can implement the equality operator on `UIImage`, which will ease your logic when it comes to comparing images:

```swift
func ==(lhs: UIImage, rhs: UIImage) -> Bool {
    lhs === rhs || lhs.pngData() == rhs.pngData()
}
```

The operator compares the PNG representation, with a shortcut if the arguments point to the same `UIImage` instance

This also enables the `!=` operator on `UIImage`.

Note that the `.pngData` call and the byte-to-byte comparison might be a time consuming operation, so care to be taken when trying to compare large images.

Answer (score 14):

You cannot compare two `UIImage` objects using the `!=` or `==` operators, one option is comparing as `NSData` using the `UIImagePNGRepresentation` to convert it to `NSData` objects, like in the following code:

```
func areEqualImages(img1: UIImage, img2: UIImage) -> Bool {

   guard let data1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img1) else { return false }
   guard let data2 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img2) else { return false }

   return data1.isEqualToData(data2)
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: For swift 4 replace UIImagePNGRepresentation(img1) with  data1 = image.pngData or  data1 = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.7)

Comment: I don't know why this happens and not sure I am completely correct but this will return NO if both images are empty images (eg initialised with no data). Even comparing the same instance to itself will return NO.

Comment: same thing happed  with me